# iOS Swift convenience initializer self used before self.init called

Tags: ios, swift

so I have been trying to create a "Period" class, with the following attributes:

```
class PTPeriod {

    // MARK: Stored Properties

    var start: Date
    var end: Date
    var place: PTPlace?


//MARK: DESIGNATED NITIALIZER
init(start: Date, end: Date, place: PTPlace? = nil) {
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.place = place

}
```

And I want to initialize it with a convenience init that accepts a dictionary like the following:

```
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 1,
              "time" : "0000"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 0,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        }
```

This is my initializer, originally I put the heavy lifting into a helper method. However, i was getting the same error I have now so I removed the helper method and the error is still occurring. Unsure where it thinks I am calling self.

**UPDATE: moved the date formatting into a date formatter extension, but the error still persists! unsure WHY. new init shown:**

My new Convenience init:

```
// MARK: Convenience init for initializing periods pulled from Google Place API
convenience init?(placeData: [String:Any], place: PTPlace? = nil) throws {
    var start: Date? = nil
    var end: Date? = nil
    var formatter = DateFormatter()

    do {
        for (key, value) in placeData {
            let period = value as! [String: Any]
            if (key == "open") {
                start = try formatter.upcoming_date(with: period)
            } else if (key == "close") {
                end = try formatter.upcoming_date(with: period)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        if (start != nil && end != nil) { self.init(start: start!, end: end!, place: place) }
        else { print("we f'd up") }

    }

    catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

Here is my DateFormatter.upcoming_date method:

```
   func upcoming_date(with googlePlacePeriod: [String: Any]) throws -> Date? {
    if let day = googlePlacePeriod["day"] as? Int {
        if (day < 0) || (day > 6) { throw SerializationError.invalid("day", day) } // throw an error if day is not between 0-6
        if let time = googlePlacePeriod["time"] as? String {
            if time.characters.count != 4 { throw SerializationError.invalid("time", time) } // throw an error if time is not 4 char long
            var upcoming_date: Date
            let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

            let current_day_of_week = Date().getDayOfWeekInt()
            let dayOfPeriod = day + 1

            ///TRUST THAT THIS WORKS... NO JODAS
            var distance = dayOfPeriod - current_day_of_week // inverse = false

            if (dayOfPeriod < current_day_of_week) {
                switch distance {
                case -1: distance = 6
                case -2: distance = 5
                case -3: distance = 4
                case -4: distance = 3
                case -5: distance = 2
                case -6: distance = 1
                default: break
                }
            }
            /** time example: "1535" translates into 3:35PM
             first two characters in string are "hour" (15)
             last two characters in string are "minute(35)
             **/

            let hour = Int(time.substring(to: time.index(time.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)))!
            let minute = Int(time.substring(from: time.index(time.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)))


            upcoming_date = Date().fastForward(amount: distance, unit: "days", inverse: false)!
            var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: upcoming_date)
            components.hour = hour
            components.minute = minute
            upcoming_date = gregorian.date(from: components)!
            return upcoming_date
        }
        else { throw SerializationError.missing("time") }
    }
    else { throw SerializationError.missing("day") }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the error in your title, but your code as listed doesn't call `self.init` in the `else` block. Similarly if an error is thrown, you're catching it (and not calling `self.init`) instead of letting it bubble up to the caller.

Comment: @Honey- I do have a designated initializer, but it requires "start" and "end" to be initialized. I will add it to the question for clarity

Comment: @Kevin- thanks for pointing that out, I'm not so sure I'm fully clear on when to catch errors and when to let them "bubble", though I've done a lot of reading on it.  I added a "return nil" for when the init fails (as its a failable initializer)

Comment: Where does the method `upcoming_date` come from? It's not related to standard `DateFormatter`(of course not because Swift methods **never** use snake case variable names). I suspect there is another `formatter` declared in the class which uses `self` when being called. You are discouraged from naming local variables and properties with the same name unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @markocalvocruz I removed my comment, it wasn't 100% correct. Where did you add the `return nil`? But basically the reason you're getting that error is, you are accessing some property ie you'r doing `self.someProperty` **before** you either do `self.init(...)` or `return nil`

Comment: @vadian, apologies, upcoming_date was originally inside the convenience init but I cut it out and added it to DateFormatter, I will include it to the original question for complete transparency and full information

Comment: @honey, Thank you. I understand that I need to call self.init early but how can I if I need to convert a dictionary into a date to get the required attributes to initialize? "start", "end" are not optionals. I don't see where I am calling self inside the initializer at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a failable initializer, so if it fails, you must `return nil` to let it know it failed:

```
if (start != nil && end != nil) { 
    self.init(start: start!, end: end!, place: place) }
} else { 
    print("we f'd up") 
    return nil
}
```

Also, in your `do`-`catch`, you need to either

- re-`throw` the error in the `catch` block

  ```
  catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      throw error
  }
  ```
- eliminate the `do`-`catch` blocks altogether; or
- just `return nil`:

  ```
  catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return nil
  }
  ```

  If you do this, you'd presumably not define this failable initializer as one that `throws` because you're no longer throwing.

---

Given that you're unlikely to do anything meaningful with the thrown error, I'd just make it a failable initializer that doesn't throw:

```
convenience init?(placeData: [String: Any], place: PTPlace? = nil) {
    var start: Date?
    var end: Date?
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    for (key, value) in placeData {
        let period = value as! [String: Any]
        if key == "open" {
            start = try? formatter.upcoming_date(with: period)
        } else if key == "close" {
            end = try? formatter.upcoming_date(with: period)
        } else {
            break  // I'm not sure why you're doing this; it seems extremely imprudent (esp since dictionaries are not ordered)
        }
    }

    if let start = start, let end = end {
        self.init(start: start, end: end, place: place)
    } else {
        print("either start or end were not found")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, you made the problem disappear!! I don't quite understand (yet) why this gave me problems but thank you. I would not have suspected this to be the issue

Comment: The trick is that in failable initializer, every path of execution must either call a designated initializer or must `return nil` (or, if the initializer `throws`, either must `throw` an actual error). You had two paths of execution (the `else` clause and the `catch` block, that failed to do so). The compiler error message is just misleading.